# Basic Unicode encoding/decoding

Tags: python, unicode, decode, encode

Python 2.7.9 / Windows environment

when I

`print myString`

I'm seeing:

`u'\u5df1\u6b66\u8d2a\u5929\u66f2'`

Now I know the console I'm using (git-bash) is capable of displaying unicode. How can I encode (or decode, which ever is the right process to do) myString so that it displays:

`己武贪天曲`

I understand that the question is very basic. If anyone has good introductory material or reference, links would be most welcomed.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3 that you're having issues? Python 3 should be able to handle it by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see is the result of `print repr(u'\u5df1\u6b66\u8d2a\u5929\u66f2')`. If `isinstancetype(myString, (str, unicode))` is true then find the source where the string is defined and fix it. If `myString` is some other type then look at how its `__str__`, `__repr__`, `__unicode__` methods are defined. To fix it; remove the code that calls unnecessary `repr()` (it can hide as a formatting operation e.g., `"%r" % o`).

To check whether your environment supports Unicode, run: `print u'\u5929'`. It should produce `天`.

If your input is a Python literal and you can't change it (you should try at the very least to switch it to json format) then you could use `ast.literal_eval(r"u'\u5929'")` to get `unicode` string object:

```
import ast

print ast.literal_eval(myString)
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't describe my situation clearly enough. I am passed the string, so I can't "find the source where the string is defined and fix it". `myString` is of type string, and it's in ASCII. The exact content is the string literal there (i.e. u'\u5df1\u6b66\u8d2a\u5929\u66f2'). I need to transform it to the corresponding unicode string.

Comment: @CharlesW.: I've updated the answer to show how to convert a Python string literal.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
message=u'\\u5df1\\u6b66\\u8d2a\\u5929\\u66f2'
print message.decode('unicode-escape')
```

I guess you are mising a "\" on every desired character

Comment: Do not use `.decode('unicode-escape')`: it treats symptoms but it leaves `u''` in the string. Find what is called `repr(u'..\u5929..')` instead.

Answer (score -2):

You should use the encode method . Consider this example :

```
str='hello'
print(str.encode(encoding='base64'))
```

For the list of available encoding , check this :

https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings